# How to insert data in multiple table in Yii

Tags: php, yii2

I am new in Yii. I need to create product module to save product data. In that i need to create two table `products` and `product_image` to save product data and multiple product images.

**Product table**

> id, category_id, , title ,price, description

**Product image table**

> id, product_id, image

I have created table as above and generated model and CRUD for product table. BUT when I goto add product page I am not getting image upload button. **I am getting just `product` table field in add product page.**

**Should I created model for two table to get image upload button ?**

How to insert data in multiple table in yii ?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATES**

**ProductController :**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Products();
        $productsImage = new ProductsImage();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'productsImage'=> $productsImage,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**My Add product form.php**

```
<div class="products-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(['0'=>'Select Parents Category']+
        ArrayHelper::map(ProductCategory::find()->all(),'id','category_name')
    ) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'price')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($productsImage,'image')->fileInput() ?> //here i am getting error of undefined variable $productsImage

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your products table there is no field for image so you are not getting upload image button. Here is many way you can do this. 1 ) You can create public variable for image button in you products model. suppose you have create public variable in products model like `public $productImage` and in view file in you can create upload button for image using this code.

```
`echo $form->fileField($model,'productImage',array('class' => 'btn'));`
```

2) Second option if you want create productImage model then you need to pass that object from create action of product. suppose in your products controller in create action you can create object of productImages model like below.

```
$productImages = new productImages;
```

and you need to pass this model variable in create view like this way

```
 $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'productImages'=> $productImages,

                ));
```

Here suppose  $model is your products model object. and in view file you can create image button like below code.

```
echo $form->fileField($productImages,'product_image',array('class' => 'btn'));
```

here 'product_image' is your column name of your product_image table.  in controller create action you will get in post object using product_images post after that save data how you want i hope you will get idea what you need to do now. hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks let me check and implement.

Comment: Hi @dinesh i used your code but i am gettin error "Undefined variable: productsImage" in view/_form.php

Comment: see i have updated my question and shared a controller code;

Comment: @DeepParekh I got the issues have you passed $productsImage variable in create.php which is in your view folder of products  if not then please pass look like <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'productImage' => $productImage,
  ''
    ]) ?>

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 provides a way to handle this situation:

**in your product controller:**

```
public function actionCreate() 
{
    $product = new app\models\Product();
    $productImages = new app\models\ProductImage();

    if($product->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $productImages->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$product, $productImages])) {

        // your other file processing code        

        $product->save();
        $productImages->save();

        // return/redirection statement
    }else {
        return $this->render(['create', 'product' => $product, 'productImages' => $productImages]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in add product page i am not getting upload image option(file upload option).

Comment: @DeepParekh please edit your question by providing your code so that it will be easier to debug...